# customize soap fault message in spring integration

Tags: soap, spring-integration

I am currently learning spring integration.I want to create a soap response from fault message.If any error is occurred spring gives response with fault in message body.I want to customize it.Instead of showing it i need to show a response object which contains pain response object.For eg:
if soap fault message is like this

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>

     <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">
        Failed to locate method (ValidateCreditCard) in class (examplesCreditCard) at /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.6/lib/site_perl/5.6.0/SOAP/Lite.pm line 1555.
     </faultstring>

  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

in its place i need to show its response as follows

```
 <m:myResponse xmlns:m ="http://www.example.org/myschema">
     <m:error> Failed to locate method (ValidateCreditCard) in class (examplesCreditCard) at /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.6/lib/site_perl/5.6.0/SOAP/Lite.pm line 1555</m:error>
</m:myResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` has `error-channel` option to provide an ability to treat any downstream Exception with some error handling flow and return a desired result from there. That result is used as a SOAP response.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Hey Artem Thanks for the Response.Just trying to check is it <int-ws:inbound-channel-adapter> or <int-ws:inbound-gateway>?I need to create response from requested payload,Can we get requested payload to error channel along with exception?

Comment: Actually the Framework does that for you with `failedMessage` on `MessagingException` from that `ErrorMesstage` on the `error-channel`. Although that `failedMessage` will be the last guilty one. So, to have an access to the original request `payload` you must enrich the message to process using `<header-enricher>` with the custom header : `<header name="requestHeader" expression="payload"/>`. And this header will be available in that `failedMessage`.